# Fill in the website form with drop-down menu with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

Writing the following VBA macro in Excel:

```
Sub compile()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "www.google.it"
IE.Visible = True

Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

IE.document.getElementById("Civico").Value = "1"

End Sub
```

the "house number" field is not filled in and I don't really know how. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't choose the dropdown list value because it isn't initialized. We need to choose value from "VCinputLoc" so that the dropdown list of "VCinputCivico" will show. You could simulate keypress instead of set value and add some wait in the code waiting dropdown initialization.

Code Sample:

```
Sub compile()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "https://fibra.planetel.it"
IE.Visible = True

Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

IE.document.getElementById("VCinputLoc").Focus
IE.document.getElementById("VCinputLoc").Value = "ROMA"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-suggestion")(0).Click
IE.document.getElementById("VCinputIndirizzo").Focus
IE.document.getElementById("VCinputIndirizzo").Value = "Piazza Del Campidoglio"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
IE.document.getElementById("VCinputCivico_chosen").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Focus
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
Application.SendKeys "1"
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'the last step can't enter the value, you could research more and I'll also continue to research
End Sub
```